# Excel - Get only values from column that are not Zero "0"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know this may sound trivial, but I have been stumped on this for a while.

***Example of what I want to happen:***
[image]

Every time I try to make this work, it doesn't shift the values up if value is zero. Ends up looking the exact same way with just the 0's missing and blank fields present. Anyone know how I would go by getting my desired output?

A and B are the provided columns.
D and E are the example of what I want the formula to actually do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `Office365` then you can use `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(A2:A12,A2:A12>0)
```

[image]

Comment: @CiscoNewb Glad to know!

Answer (score 1):

In "Output" `D2`, enter formula, copied right to `E2` and all copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$2:A$12)/(A$2:A$12>0),ROW(A1))),"")
```

[image]